# Parsing JSON in Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working with JSON for the first time, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I'm trying to use a JSON file to populate data in a Google Sheet. I just don't know the right syntax. How can I format a JSON function to properly access the data and stop returning an error?

I'm trying to pull data from here:

https://eddb.io/archive/v6/bodies_recently.jsonl

into a Google Sheets.

I've got the ImportJSON script loaded and I've tested it with a really small JSON file (http://date.jsontest.com/) and it works as advertised, using this function:

```
=ImportJSON("http://date.jsontest.com", "/date")
```

However, when I try to use the same function with the JSON from eddb.io above, I can't get it to work.

What I would like to do is pull the "name" into A1 and then a few of the attributes into columns, like so:

```
name  id  type_name  rotational_period, etc.
```

Here's a link to my tests:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gCKpLcf-ytbPNcuQIIzxp1RMy7N5K8pD02hCLnL27qQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My guess is the second json contain lists, and can't converted to a sheet

Comment: You're referencing https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

Answer (score 4):

How about this workaround?

### Reason of issue:

When I saw the URL of `https://eddb.io/archive/v6/bodies_recently.jsonl`, I noticed that the extension of the file is `jsonl`. So when I checked the values retrieved from `https://eddb.io/archive/v6/bodies_recently.jsonl`, it was found that the values were JSON Lines. This has already been mentioned by [Dimu Designs's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047848/parsing-json-in-google-sheets#comment98741238_56048230). Also I could confirm that the official document says `bodies_recently.jsonl` is Line-delimited JSON.

### Workaround:

Unfortunately, ImportJSON cannot directly parse the values of JSON Lines. So it is required to modify the script as a workaround. In your shared Spreadsheet, the script of ImportJSON is put as the container-bound script. In this modification, I modified the script. Please modify as follows.

#### From:

The following function can be seen at the line of 130 - 135 in your script editor.

```
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

#### To:

Please replace the above function to the following script, and save the script. Then, please put `=ImportJSON("https://eddb.io/archive/v6/bodies_recently.jsonl", "/id")` to a cell, again.

```
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var object = jsondata.getContentText().match(/{[\w\s\S].+}/g).map(function(e) {return JSON.parse(e)}); // Modified

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

### Note:

- Although this modified script works for the values from `https://eddb.io/archive/v6/bodies_recently.jsonl`, I'm not sure whether this modified script works for all JSON lines values. I apologize for this.

### References:

- [eddb.io/api](https://eddb.io/api)
- [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not with my laptop, but I see you getting the error `SyntaxError: Expected end of stream at char 2028 (line 132)`.

I think the data you received from the URL is to long.

Comment: Thanks. The json may also be malformed. I've tried to put the file in this :https://jsoneditoronline.org/ and it returns errors.

Comment: The data payload is in JSON Lines format, which is distinct from pure JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`=IMPORTDATA(E1)`** and get the whole chunk into sheets and then **`REGEXEXTRACT`** all parts you need

[image: 0]

Comment: yeah, typo, sry... fixed