# With what frequency is my script calling the API? I don't want to get cut off

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a json script from [another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047848/parsing-json-in-google-sheets) and don't know with what frequency I'm calling the external data (from Seatgeek).

I don't want to get cut off from the Seatgeek api so I want to make sure I'm not going to bog down the system - I really only need the data to refresh twice a day.

I would not consider myself a developer so I'm not sure where to look. Can someone please help by taking a look at the [script](https://script.google.com/d/Mg7e3sb6exgf-h3YQVAWAubkHX3xEP0vk/edit?mid=ACjPJvF1KiaraAqyy3Gua-UR46oh1lVt2vEU1qFzjo-9MJVWyDlujQEeMrwsKek5zbk7WrZare7Fz9OipiMVkDen3obJM-kxiLe4QuN5-AIHbv5dUBR2o8tUT1e8matL3g6706KB-usj9g&uiv=2)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits):

> Google Sheets API has a limit of 500 requests per 100 seconds per project, and 100 requests per 100 seconds per user. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.

Also, if you want to find the usage and more statistics regarding the API, you can check the Google API console and find all the information there.

For more information regarding your issue, you could check the following documentation:

[1] [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits);

[2] [Google Console API Quota](https://support.google.com/supportu/answer/2700653?hl=en)

Comment: Hey @ale13 - quick clarification in my original post (edited). I'm calling the data from an external API and writing it to google sheets. Should I be concerned about both google sheets and the Stubhub parameters? My assumption (and again I'm new so maybe this is totally wrong) is only the endpoint would limit my calls.. I didn't think sheets would care how often I send out a get request.

Comment: Hello @econobro, a custom function (like the one you have used) is executed when inserted into a cell. So whenever you refresh the worksheet, the last value obtained will be used, hence, only one request will be used per cell. Cheers!

Comment: Still not sure I'm understanding @ale13 but let me try to clarify (thanks for your patience).. 

So I can set up 500 cells with different API calls within a workbook with no issues.

I could set that up for four different workbooks each with 500 API calls (as long as they're on different projects)?

My concern was about the endpoint restricting my calls. I don't know with what frequency (miliseconds, seconds, etc) the data is being called from Seatgeek. How do I find out if Seatgeek will cut me off?

Comment: I'm not willing to mark this as answered. I'd like to know what millisecond interval the  json script calls the endpoint and that hasn't been resolved above.