# Using importjson when cell is an URL, JSON format in Gsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula, pygsheets

I was looking for a solution that could help me to format *JSON* input into *GSheets* output (split in row and column). I would like to use `=importjson` but my function is a CELL instead of a URL.

I have attached an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sgwxCQDLb_G-cmRsQqZU3IssUsmCXJRMaNOLbPmME4U/edit?usp=sharing) of input and output.
Hope that someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no =IMPORTJSON function on Google Sheets, you can check all the functions available here: https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

To import JSON you will have to create a script to get the JSON data, parse the data and then put it on your sheet.

---

**Edit:**

In the case you attached on the comment, you have to modify the script to not get the URL but to get the values of your cell.

To do that you can use the [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) method.

This is the example:

```
// Get a range A1:D4 on sheet titled "Invoices"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = ss.getRange("Invoices!A1:D4");

// Get cell A1 on the first sheet
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
```

Maybe this post can help you as well:

[Parsing JSON in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047848/parsing-json-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Hi Kessy,
[This](https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-import-json-importjson-function/) is one example of script, but I'm not using a URL, my JSON output is in a cell, like the Sample on GSHEET I have attached

Answer (score 0):

actually, ImportJSON has a different option - **ImportJSONfromsheet**, where you use a sheet or a specificrange as an input

Answer (score 0):

There is an option when you can use no functions and no special script. What you can do is install the add-on, complete the form with required parameters (see the screenshot below), configure a schedule for updates, and just run it for the first time. You can find a more detailed instruction here on how to import [JSON to Google Sheets](https://blog.coupler.io/how-to-import-json-to-google-sheets-without-coding/).

[image: import from JSON to Google Sheets]